# Can't start tor

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, windows

Tor seems to give me this error everytime I try to connect using obfs4. None of the provided bridges seem to work.

```
12/26/2016 12:55:11 PM.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12/26/2016 12:55:11 PM.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12/26/2016 12:55:11 PM.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12/26/2016 12:55:11 PM.200 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
12/26/2016 12:55:12 PM.000 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
12/26/2016 12:55:12 PM.000 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
12/26/2016 12:55:13 PM.600 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
12/26/2016 12:55:13 PM.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12/26/2016 12:55:13 PM.600 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
12/26/2016 12:55:13 PM.900 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set. 
12/26/2016 12:55:18 PM.500 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12/26/2016 12:55:18 PM.500 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
12/26/2016 12:55:18 PM.500 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12/26/2016 12:55:18 PM.500 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
12/26/2016 12:55:27 PM.300 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection 
12/26/2016 12:55:46 PM.000 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.9:12166 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
12/26/2016 12:55:46 PM.000 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.13:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
12/26/2016 12:55:48 PM.600 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.105.109.165:10527 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
12/26/2016 12:55:48 PM.600 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 83.212.101.3:50002 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
12/26/2016 12:55:49 PM.300 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.105.109.147:13764 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
12/26/2016 12:56:00 PM.000 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 192.99.11.54:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
12/26/2016 12:56:00 PM.000 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 198.245.60.50:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
12/26/2016 12:56:00 PM.000 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 192.95.36.142:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
12/26/2016 12:56:10 PM.000 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.11:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
12/26/2016 12:56:10 PM.000 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.12:4304 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
12/26/2016 12:56:10 PM.000 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.10:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
12/26/2016 12:56:14 PM.500 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
12/26/2016 12:56:14 PM.500 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
12/26/2016 12:56:14 PM.500 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
```

It says disablenetwork is set a lot, but I don't know how to disable disablenetwork.

Comment: Use obfs4 bridges from bridgedb https://bridges.torproject.org

Comment: @canonizingironize It's blocked, I've tried bridges@torproject.org but none of those seem to be working, unless I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: If obfs4 doesn't work then try meek-amazon and meek-azure. If they don't work you'll need to find some other means to bypass whatever local censorship is blocking access to Tor.

Comment: @canonizingironize Can you nudge me in the right direction to find a way to bypass?

Comment: Anything that lets you make a connection out to some server that isn't censored and then allows you to make a further connection out to the internet, e.g. ssh proxying, a vpn, etc, etc. it depends on the censorship. there is no global and guaranteed solutions to such problems, it is always an armsrace between censors and evasion techniques.

Comment: There is a *lot's* of ways to bypass the censorship of Tor. Read about all of them here: <https://www.torproject.org/docs/bridges>